# Measure Units/Precision in Altium Designer

Tags: pcb, altium

I want to see at least four digits after the dot in Altium Designer measurement units and coordinates. Is there a way to do this?

It shows only three digits after the dot and then rounds the number according to the number entered.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

- Open "Preferences" dialog.
- Find "PCB Editor" from the list to the left, and expand it.
- Find "Defaults" and click on it. Now you'll see a list of defaults under "Primitive List" on the centre.

You can click on any of the "XXX Dimension" items (e.g. Ordinate Dimension, Linear Dimension, Radial Dimension etc) and you can change the `Primary Units` and `Value Precision` values under "Units" to the right, as well as formatting under "Value" to the bottom-right. I don't know the maximum precision you can go for.

Comment: I changed it, but there was no change in the values I expected

Comment: @Electronx you should change the most relevant "XXX Dimension" item. But this is what Altium provides, and there's no other way to change it. There must be a hard-coded maximum precision of course because beyond a certain point it becomes impractical and meaningless. To me, 1 um precision for a general dimension (track, hole diameter, etc) is too much. Maybe the developers thought about a similar thing.

Answer (score 0):

1. Close all the PCB documents.
2. Open to Setup System Preference (the gear icon top right).
3. Go to general tab under PCB editor, in Metric Display Precision you can change number of digits.
4. Restart Altium to see the changes

Comment: thats not working on me